# #catboost - Loss_function MultiRMSEWithUncertainty

Tags: catboostregressor

Quick question: is there posibility to get uncertainty (variance vectors) for a multi target regression problem -> CatBoost MultiRMSE loss function (MultiRMSEWithUncertainty)?
Many Thanks
Alex

params = {'loss_function': 'MultiRMSEWithUncertainty',  'eval_metric': 'MultiRMSE'}